# ASP.NET form validator display dynamic, adjust CSS of input?

Tags: asp.net, validation, client-side-validation

I've got my dynamic validator working, (its creating a span on invalidation client-side), is there a way to control the styling of the invalid input on client-side val? I want to give it a redish background. Looking for a light-weight simplistic solution but open to all options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[To Exactly quote a previous answer of mine:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891206/creating-a-custom-response-with-asp-net-validation-controls/6894060#6894060)

This article might help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx

Particularly this section (look for "Client Side Validation" then under there, "Special Effects"):

```
<asp:Label id=lblZip runat=server 
   Text="Zip Code:"/> 
<asp:TextBox id=txtZip runat=server 
   OnChange="txtZipOnChange();" /></asp:TextBox><br>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id=valZip runat=server
   ControlToValidate=txtZip
   ErrorMessage="Invalid Zip Code" 
   ValidationExpression="[0-9]{5}" /><br>

<script language=javascript>
function txtZipOnChange() {
   // Do nothing if client validation is not active
   if (typeof(Page_Validators) == "undefined")  return;
   // Change the color of the label
   txtZip.style.color = valZip.isvalid ? "Black" : "Red";
}
</script>
```

There is still some wiring up that needs to be done, which you may be able to tidy up with some jQuery or the like